# Regex for replacing all underlines except if they are part of a hashtag

Tags: python, regex

I don't know how to write a regex statement in order to replace all *underlines* to `' '` except if the underline is a part of an hashtag statement. 
For example if we have a text, we want to replace all of underlines except for cases like *#please_help_me*.

Comment: It looks like you want us to write some code for you. While many users are willing to produce code for a coder in distress, they usually only help when the poster has already tried to solve the problem on their own. A good way to demonstrate this effort is to include the code you've written so far, example input (if there is any), the expected output, and the output you actually get (console output, tracebacks, etc.). The more detail you provide, the more answers you are likely to receive. Check the [FAQ] and [ask].

Comment: You're right but honestly I am not good enough to write even a part of it.

Comment: @GhazalehKharadpoor: Then perhaps you could give it an attempt without the use of regex?

Comment: @Simon'ReinstateMonica'Shine I can but I am curious about the regex format :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest way would probably be to match *all contiguous words with underscores in them*, then pass a function/lambda to [`re.sub`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.sub) to remove the underscores the old-fashioned way, only if the first character is not `#`:

```
sample = 'Here is_a_sample string #with_a_hashtag'
rstr = r'(#?(?:\w*_)+)'
# in this case, this matches like so:
#    'is_a_'
#    '#with_a_'
new_sample = re.sub(rstr, 
    lambda s: s.group(0) if s.group(0).startswith('#') else s.group(0).replace('_', ' '), 
    sample)
print(new_sample)
# 'Here is a sample string #with_a_hashtag'
```

The regex involved here is pretty simple:

- as a match group (`()`),
- zero or one `#` symbols (`#?`)
- followed by the non-matching group, repeated at least once, of (`(?: )+`)
- any number of word-like characters followed by an underscore (`\w*_`)